# How to update multiple fields of a django model instance?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm wondering, what is a standard way of updating multiple fields of an instance of a model in django? ... If I have a model with some fields,

```
Class foomodel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    ...
```

... and I instantiate it with one field given, and then in a separate step I want to provide the rest of the fields, how do I do that by just passing a dictionary or key value params? Possible?

In other words, say I have a dictionary with some data in it that has everything I want to write into an instance of that model. The model instance has been instantiated in a separate step and let's say it hasn't been persisted yet. I can say `foo_instance.field1 = my_data_dict['field1']` for each field, but something tells me there should be a way of calling a method on the model instance where I just pass all of the field-value pairs at once and it updates them. Something like `foo_instance.update(my_data_dict)`. I don't see any built-in methods like this, am I missing it or how is this efficiently done?

I have a feeling this is an obvious, RTM kind of question but I just haven't seen it in the docs.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

It's tempting to mess with `__dict__`, but that won't apply to attributes inherited from a parent class.

You can either iterate over the dict to assign to the object:

```
for (key, value) in my_data_dict.items():
    setattr(obj, key, value)
obj.save()
```

Or you can directly modify it from a queryset (making sure your query set only returns the object you're interested in):

```
FooModel.objects.filter(whatever="anything").update(**my_data_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks @Wilfred. Quite helpful. For others: don't forget to do `obj.save()` after the for loop

Comment: Be ware that the `FooModel.objects.filter(whatever="anything").update(**my_data_dict)` bypasses the save method. You might end up saving things that should throw exceptions.

Comment: Thanks. The first option is preferable if you want to avoid running the same query twice during update however second option is easier to run and its' readable.

Answer (score 36):

You could try this:

```
obj.__dict__.update(my_data_dict)
```

Comment: This won't apply to inherited attributes.

Comment: What are the implications of the fact that it won't apply to inherited attributes?

Comment: Also, is you are trying to update a ForeignKey, using __dict__, related values   name are `field_name_id` not `field_name`, you need to be careful with that.

Comment: This didn't persist my record... what might I be missing?

Comment: @tomascharad - you would have to call it like `obj.__dict__.update(my_data_dict)` then `obj.save()` to persist the data.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like such a natural thing you'd want to do but like you I've not found it in the docs either.  The docs do say you should sub-class save() on the model.  And that's what I do.

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    mfields = iter(self._meta.fields)
    mods = [(f.attname, kwargs[f.attname]) for f in mfields if f.attname in kwargs]
    for fname, fval in mods: setattr(self, fname, fval)
    super(MyModel, self).save()
```

Comment: Thinking of making a decorator for models that adds a new method "dict_save" (so 2 save methods for the model - normal and dict) with the body above the next time I need this. I looked up the code I used to do this and it's the same except that I was doing it outside of save. Had a method update_model_obj_from_dict(model_object, update_dict) with virtually the same body as above and expected that  I would choose when to call save() after. I kind of like having the choice. so maybe a method on the model called "set_from_dict" with everything above except the last line and just using save later.

Answer (score 4):

I get primary key's name, use it to filter with `Queryset.filter()` and update with `Queryset.update()`.

```
fooinstance = ...    
# Find primary key and make a dict for filter
pk_name foomodel._meta.pk.name
filtr = {pk_name: getattr(fooinstance, pk_name)}
# Create a dict attribute to update
updat = {'name': 'foo', 'lastname': 'bar'}
# Apply
foomodel.objects.filter(**filtr).update(**updat)
```

This allows me to update an instance whatever the primary key.

Answer (score 4):

Update using `update()`

```
Discussion.objects.filter(slug=d.slug)
    .update(title=form_data['title'],
            category=get_object_or_404(Category, pk=form_data['category']),
            description=form_data['description'], closed=True)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When posting answers please include an explanation of your code and remember to format the text.

Comment: Important to note that this does not call the save() method nor the pre_save/post_save signals.

Comment: @Maxim is there a way to trigger those signals manually since the `save()` method was never called?

Comment: @enchance you'd have to call the save method on each instance as the update method doesn't call it nor send the pre/post save signals. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#update