# How to Set Multiple Fields in Django Db Record

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like to know the best way to set the values for multiple fields of an existing Django model object.  I have a model that includes many fields:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    Field1 = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    Field2 = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    Field3 = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    etc...
```

Also I have dictionary containing changes to a subset of those fields for a particular record:

```
data = {'field1': 'value1', 'field5': 'value5', 'field7': 'value7'}
record = Foo.objects.get(pk=1)
```

I want to set the fields in `record` with the new values in `data`.  What is the best way to go about this?  Is there a way to unpack the dictionary and have it modify the appropriate fields in the record?  I realize I can iterate over the dictionary using:

```
for k, v in data.iteritems():
     setattr(entry, k, v)
entry.save()
```

I was thinking there might be a way to call something like:

```
entry.set_values(**data)
```

Is there anything like this or am I going down the wrong path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't tested this myself, but you can probably pass a dict to the .update() function from the Queryset API: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#update

```
Foo.objects.get(pk=1).update(**data)
```

Comment: Update is only available on querysets but this works Foo.objects.filter(pk=1).update(**data).  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Do note that this will not fire any of the save-related signals, nor call .save() on the instance. This may be a desired situation, or a deal-breaker. You can do `Foo.objects.filter(pk=1).update(**date); Foo.objects.get(pk=1).save()` if you need this to fire.

Comment: See this question too:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576664/how-to-update-multiple-fields-of-a-django-model-instance

Comment: the is link broken.

Comment: @Cyzanfar Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Correction on @brandon answer.

Make sure to use .filter() method instead of .get()
since .get method returns matching object or raise DoesNotExist exception

*Wrong :* Foo.objects.**get(pk=1)**.update(**data)

*Correct :* Foo.objects.**filter(pk=1)**.update(**data)