# How to update() a single model instance retrieved by get() on Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, model, django-orm

I have a function which currently calls `Models.object.get()`, which returns either 0 or 1 model objects:

- if it returns 0, I create a new model instance in the `except DoesNotExist` clause of the function.
- Otherwise, I would like to update the fields in the pre-existing
  instance, without creating a new one.

I was originally attempting to
call `.update()` on the instance which was found, but `.update()`
seems to be only callable on a QuerySets. How do I get around
changing a dozen fields, without calling `.filter()` and comparing
the lengths to know if I have to create or update a pre-existing
instance?

Comment: First you can use get_or_create, then you could show some code...

Answer (score 118, accepted):

With the advent of Django 1.7, there is now a new [`update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) QuerySet method, which should do exactly what you want. Just be careful of potential race conditions if uniqueness is not enforced at the database level.

**Example from the documentation:**

```
obj, created = Person.objects.update_or_create(
    first_name='John', last_name='Lennon',
    defaults={'first_name': 'Bob'},
)
```

> The `update_or_create` method tries to fetch an object from database
>   based on the given **kwargs**. If a match is found, it updates the
>   fields passed in the `defaults` dictionary.

---

Pre-Django 1.7:

Change the model field values as appropriate, then call `.save()` to persist the changes:

```
try:
    obj = Model.objects.get(field=value)
    obj.field = new_value
    obj.save()
except Model.DoesNotExist:
    obj = Model.objects.create(field=new_value)
# do something else with obj if need be
```

Comment: But suppose I have 20 fields, is there an easier way to update them? With .update() I suppose I can just pass in **kwargs?

Comment: Try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576664/how-to-update-multiple-fields-of-a-django-model-instance

Comment: This approach has atomicity problems -- if two app instances both change the same instance in the DB,one could clobber the other.

Comment: Also use this only if you work with the object. If you just want to update, it would be much better to use filter with the corresponding pk attribute. This has the advantage that only one query is issued. If you use get for an update, two queries are used.

Comment: @zhuyxn `for attr, val in kwargs.iteritems(): setattr(obj, attr, val)`

Comment: `.update_or_create()` also uses `.save()` under the hood, so it has the same effect at the end of the day if the obj exists, which you might want to avoid

Answer (score 67):

if you want only to update model if exist (without create it):

```
Model.objects.filter(id = 223).update(field1 = 2)
```

mysql query:

```
UPDATE `model` SET `field1` = 2 WHERE `model`.`id` = 223
```

Comment: he is asking using .get() specifically  not  .filter()

Comment: Also use `.first()` if you guys want some check-up model field before execute db query, since `.filter()` should using unique id as parameter

Comment: I'm getting `object has no attribute 'update'`

Answer (score 47):

As of Django 1.5, there is an update_fields property on model save. eg:

`obj.save(update_fields=['field1', 'field2', ...])`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/

I prefer this approach because it doesn't create an atomicity problem if you have multiple web app instances changing different parts of a model instance.

Comment: updated_fields is a list not dictionary then how we will pass the updated value for the field?

Comment: @brainLoop, you wouldn't pass the values separately. You would set them on the object itself. obj.field1=value before calling save on the obj.

Comment: update_fields argument prevents race conditions by forcing an update to the model for the specified fields. This way we avoid loading the model into memory and then saving which means that even if another application instance exists, it can't do anything in between.

Answer (score 30):

I don't know how good or bad this is, but you can try something like this:

```
try:
    obj = Model.objects.get(id=some_id)
except Model.DoesNotExist:
    obj = Model.objects.create()
obj.__dict__.update(your_fields_dict) 
obj.save()
```

Comment: Exceptions are heavy operations and not recommended

Comment: Exceptions are reasonable and correct.
NOTE:  create() in this answer should be create(id=some_id) and have its own try/except block to handle duplicate keys and/or race conditions, be run in a retry-mechanism, etc.

Comment: Exceptions are the python way and are not heavy and are recommended.

Comment: This answer is what I want.

Comment: despite the way of getting the obj, obj.__dict__.update(your_fields_dict) , is the best method for me. thanks

Answer (score 12):

Here's a mixin that you can mix into any model class which gives each instance an `update` method:

```
class UpdateMixin(object):
    def update(self, **kwargs):
        if self._state.adding:
            raise self.DoesNotExist
        for field, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, field, value)
        self.save(update_fields=kwargs.keys())
```

The `self._state.adding` check checks to see if the model is saved to the database, and if not, raises an error.

*(Note: This `update` method is for when you want to update a model and you know the instance is already saved to the database, directly answering the original question. The built-in `update_or_create` method featured in Platinum Azure's answer already covers the other use-case.)*

You would use it like this (after mixing this into your user model):

```
user = request.user
user.update(favorite_food="ramen")
```

Besides having a nicer API, another advantage to this approach is that it calls the `pre_save` and `post_save` hooks, while still avoiding atomicity issues if another process is updating the same model.

Answer (score 5):

As @Nils mentionned, you can use the `update_fields` keyword argument of the `save()` method to manually specify the fields to update.

```
obj_instance = Model.objects.get(field=value)
obj_instance.field = new_value
obj_instance.field2 = new_value2

obj_instance.save(update_fields=['field', 'field2'])
```

The `update_fields` value should be a list of the fields to update as strings.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save

Answer (score 1):

update:

1 - **individual instance :**
get instance and update manually get() retrieve individual object

```
post = Post.objects.get(id=1)
post.title = "update title"
post.save()
```

2 - **Set of instances :**
use update() method that works only with queryset that what would be returned by filter() method

```
Post.objects.filter(author='ahmed').update(title='updated title for ahmed')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code in such cases:

```
obj, created = Model.objects.get_or_create(id=some_id)

if not created:
   resp= "It was created"
else:
   resp= "OK"
   obj.save()
```