# Update queryset in Django in following situation?

Tags: django, sql-update, django-queryset

I want to update data in Django model like this:

```
 video_id = request.POST['video_id']
     # Get the form data and update the data

 video = VideoInfoForm(request.POST)

 VideoInfo.objects.filter(id=video_id).update(video)

  return HttpResponseRedirect('/main/')
```

The new data is supplied by user in a form. I want to update data with `id=video_id`. This gives me following error:

```
update() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  25.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  86.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/zurelsoft/virtualenv/videoManagement/VideoManagementSystem/video/views.py" in post
  126.          VideoInfo.objects.filter(id=video_id).update(video)

Exception Type: TypeError at /updateVideo/
Exception Value: update() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to update?

Comment: check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once

Comment: Update record where id=video_id

Comment: I want to update all the fields.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `update` function only take keyword arguments, no generic arguments, that's why you get the `update() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)` error message.

Try:

```
VideoInfo.objects.filter(id=video_id).update(foo=video)
```

Where your models are :

```
class Video(models.Model):
    ...

class VideoInfo(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Video)
    ...
```

Note that the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) linked in comment by lazy functor shows the signature of the `update` function.

Answer (score 3):

For sure you can't pass a form instance to `update()` since it takes exactly one argument. Read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once). So if you want to update one field:

```
VideoInfo.objects.filter(id=video_id).update(video_name=request.POST['video_name'])
```

It seems there isn't any official method to update multiple fields at one, but you can try this:

```
data_dict = {'video_name': 'Test name', 'video_description': 'Something'}

VideoInfo.objects.filter(id=video_id).update(**data_dict)
```

Since `request.POST` is a dict, you can try to use it instead of data_dict but make sure the key match your field name in DB.

Another method has been discussed here: [How to update multiple fields of a django model instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576664/how-to-update-multiple-fields-of-a-django-model-instance) but it looks kinda hacky.

Comment: Using value from requsts.POST directly in the SQL query without any validation or sanitization is asking for trouble.